# Getting info about the model in relationship table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and i may have missed something,

I have 3 models: Employee, List and List_to_employee (relationship model).

**Employee model**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :list_to_employees, foreign_key: "employee_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :lists
end
```

**Employee controller**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_employee, only: [:my_lists]

  def my_lists
    if !@employee.nil?
      @lists = @employee.list_to_employees
    end
  end

  def set_employee
    @employee = Employee.find_by(username: 'xxxx')
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :id, :email, :username)
  end

end
```

**Employee view**

```
<% if !@lists.nil? %>
    <% @lists.each do |list| %>
        <% list_info = List.find_by(id: list.id) %>
        <li><%=list_info.name%></li>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    No lists found.
<% end %>
```

My question is, what's the rails way for getting the `list_info` ? I assume that using find_by in the view is far from the best solution, so how do i get the info according to the list id i got from the `list_to_employees` relationship table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the `through: :list_to_employees` in second association as:

```
has_many :lists, through: :list_to_employees
```

Now, in your controller you can get the lists directly.

```
@lists = @employee.lists
```

In your view, just loop through the list. No need to get the values from the join table if you don't have any additional stuff there.

```
<% if !@lists.nil? %>
  <% @lists.each do |list| %>
    <li><%= list.name %></li>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No lists found.
<% end %>
```

That's it. :)